# Populating Row Number on new column for table without primary key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table where I am adding a new column to indicate row numbers. This table doesn't have any primary key associated, so I am not sure how I can populate it with row number values.

Here is the code I have put in the CTE but in the primary table I don't know how to correlate the Id column. Id is the newly added column to which I need to start the numbering.

```
;with CTE_RowNum as (
    select  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RowId
        ,Id 
    from dbo.Test
)
```

I can partition the table on certain columns but how would I join such criteria with original table?

---

Edit- Here is the schema that I am referring to. Id is the newly added column which I want to populate with as row numbers. Name and Error column together form the uniqueness.

Expected Output would be -

```
1,ABC,Time Out Issue
2,ABC,Page Not Found
3,DEF,Page Not Found
```

The order doesn't matter, I mean the last row can have '1' and the others some other value.

The other way I can think of repopulating data into a new table with Identity inserted but was just wondering is there a way to do that through T-SQL?

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    Id INT
    ,Name NVARCHAR(100)
    ,Error NVARCHAR(100)

)

INSERT INTO #Test (Name,Error) VALUES 
    ('ABC','Time Out Issue')
    ,('ABC','Page Not Found')
    ,('DEF','Page Not Found')
```

Comment: Are all rows are distinct in your table? If so, you can try with `BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)` instead of `NEWID()` . E.g. `SELECT * , RowId =  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)) FROM sys.objects`

Comment: Can you prove ample data and expected result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really simple:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RowId
    FROM   #test
)

UPDATE cte
    SET Id = RowId
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did get till this but I wasn't sure what to put in the where clause. Frankly I am little curious on how it works, which row is getting assigned to which Id on what basis. Any inkling?

Comment: It doesn't really matter since you want the row number to be random